# How I create trigger before delete and save the username who login my program?

Tags: sql, triggers, rdbms

i have table1

```
name : Phone : deletedby : Date
1       mmm       02156
```

table2 save data before delete,

```
name   Phone  deletedby  Date
1 mmm  02156   admin     22/7/2016
```

Comment: what do you mean by save username,do you want store info of who deleted it in t1 when delete occurs on t2?

Comment: also please tag the RDBMS you are  using

Comment: yes i want save who delete the record when he delete record from table1,and save this recod in table2

Comment: Also tag the RDBMS involved

Comment: @TheGameiswar RDBMS you are using : mssql, mysql, oracle and so on, not the word rdbms

Comment: @JanWalczak:sure :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_DELETE
ON table1
FOR DELETE
AS
     INSERT INTO table2 (name,Phone,deletedby,Date)
     SELECT name,Phone,User_Name(),getdate()
     FROM DELETED
```

Comment: User_Name() doesn't show the Login-name.